# Scilab compilation "cannot allocate this quantity of memory"

Tags: c++, c, scilab

I am facing issues with memory allocation in Scilab after compiling.

I am compiling on a Red Hat on ppc64 (POWER8). Stack limits are already set to unlimited (`ulimit -s unlimited`). The `./configure` script (with several options I am not showing here) runs successfully, but the `make all` fails and stops. When it stops, it is stuck at the Scilab command prompt with this message:

```
./bin/scilab-cli -ns -noatomsautoload -f modules/functions/scripts/buildmacros/buildmacros.sce
stacksize(5000000);
                   !--error 10001
stacksize: Cannot allocate memory.
%s: Cannot allocate this quantity of memory.

at line      27 of exec file called by :
exec('modules/functions/scripts/buildmacros/buildmacros.sce',-1)

-->
```

I have investigated a bit, and that error message seems to be called of course at line `00027` in `buildmatros.sce`, where the function `stacksize(5000000)` is called.

This function is defined in:

```
 scilab-5.5.1/modules/core/sci_gateway/c/sci_stacksize.c
```

I found a version of the file at this page: http://doxygen.scilab.org/master_wg/d5/dfb/sci__stacksize_8c_source.html.
The condition that is FALSE and that triggers the message seems to me to show up at line 00295.

Inside that file, you see that error is displayed whenever the `stacksize` given as input is LARGER than what is returned by the method `get_max_memory_for_scilab_stack()` from the class:

```
scilab-5.5.1/modules/core/src/c/stackinfo.c
```

Again I found a version online at the following page:
http://doxygen.scilab.org/master_wg/dd/dfb/stackinfo_8h.html#afbd65a57df45bed9445a7393a4558395
The Method is declared from line `109`.

It seems to invoke a variable called `MAXLONG`, which is however NEVER explicitly declared! As you see, it is declared several times (line `00019`, `00035`, `00043`, `00050`), but all lines are commented! *[correction: the lines are NOT commented, it was my false understanding of # being a comment sign, but it's not]*

So my guess is: `MAXLONG` is not declared, so the function does not return a value (or it returns 0) and therefore the error message is triggered because the `stacksize` given as input is higher than 0 or `NULL` or `N/A`.

My questions are then:

- Why are all lines commented where MAXLONG is defined?
- Where does MAXLONG originate from? Is it something passed from the kernel?
- How can I solve the problem?

Thanks!

PS - I tried to uncomment the line in `buildmacros`, and it compiled and installed without issues. However, when I started `scilab-cli`, it displayed the same message again.

---

Edit after further investigation:

After further investigation, I found out that what I thought were the comments are indeed instructions for the compiler... but I kept those errors of mine, so that the answer to my question is understandable.

Here are my new points.

In Scilab I noticed that by giving an input stacksize out of bounds, the same method `get_max_memory_for_scilab_stack()` is invoked, to get the upper bound. The lower bound I've seen it's defined by default.

```
-->stacksize(1)
             !--error 1504
stacksize: Out of bounds value. Not in [180000,268435454].
```

Also the stacksize used seems fine:

```
-->stacksize()
 ans  =

    7999994.    332.
```

However, when trying to give such value an input inbetween, it fails.

```
-->stacksize(1)
             !--error 1504
stacksize: Out of bounds value. Not in [180000,268435454].
```

Comment: It is defined in: `stackinfo.c line 00035 #define MAXLONG LONG_MAX`, which should be 2 GB, so max should be 2GB/8 or 256M.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to invoke a variable called MAXLONG

It's not a variable, but a pre-processor macro.

> Why are all lines commented where MAXLONG is defined?

You should ask that from the person who commented the lines. They're *not* commented in scilab-5.5.1 that's [online](http://fossies.org/dox/scilab-5.5.1-src/stackinfo_8c_source.html).

> Where does MAXLONG originate from? Is it something passed from the kernel?

It's defined in the file `scilab-5.5.1/modules/core/src/c/stackinfo.c`. It's defined to the same value as `LONG_MAX` which is defined by the standard c library (`<limits.h>` header). If the macro is not supplied by the standard library, then it's defined to some other, platform specific value.

> How can I solve the problem?

If your problem originates from the lack of definition for `MAXLONG`, then you must define it. One way going about it is to uncomment the lines that define it. Or re-download the original sources since yours don't appear to match with the official ones.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! My bad, I thought all those "#" meant those lines were commented, but actually no, that was not a comment sign, they were actual inputs for the Compiler. I do have the original sources, so I will look further in `limits.h` and other macros.

Comment: If I run a search for limits.h libraries, I find many (one is coming with Advance Tolchain, a specific set of compiler libraries for the ppc64 platform). How can I get which is the library taken by the compiler during compilation?

Comment: Well, you could try adding `#error` directive to the files one by one until your program stops compiling. On the other hand, standard headers are not guaranteed to be in files, so it might be that none of the files you found are used.

Comment: Thanks! But I just found out how to the location of those header files. You need to run: `cpp -v`, and you will see where the compiler looks for `limits.h`. In those file however, LONG_MAX is defined like that: `define LONG_MAX __LONG_MAX__`. Is that normal? What does that mean?

Comment: @Andrea yes, it's normal. It means that the `LONG_MAX` is defined to the value of `__LONG_MAX__`. `__LONG_MAX__` is yet another indentifier, possibly a pre-processor macro. I'ts defined by the implementation which you can tell by it starting with double underscores. Such identifiers are reserved for the implementation.